# Chaining promises in SignalR

Tags: jquery, signalr

Should this be working? I want to chain the read func in between start and done. I cant get it to work. The final obj is just some internal SignalR object. I'm using SignalR 2.2

```
var app = $.connection.appHub;

$.connection.hub.start()
  .then(function() {
    return app.server.read();
  })
  .done(function (obj) {

  console.log(obj); // Should be the result from the read promise, but is not
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it should work. You can see sth if your function 'read' returns a value.

```
 [HubName("appHub")]
    public class AppHub : Hub
    {
        public string Read()
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
```